# Disabling Joomla component com_content

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

Just trying to understand the working of `com_content` component in Joomla 3. Is it possible to disable or uninstall `com_content` component? Is it a core component that is essential for the functioning of the entire framework, so it cannot be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable or uninstall any core components such as `com_content`. They are protected. I'm not sure of the exact things that require `com_content`, however completely removing it which would have to be done by deleting the folders and removing any reference to it in the database could possibly and most likely result your site malfunctioning. It's therefore protected for good reason ;)

I do know that in either Joomla 3.5 or 4.0, there will be an option to install core components with installing Joomla.

Comment: Yes I thought so. Thanks for confirming. I think the `com_content` is used for displaying Articles and Categories in the admin section.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Also component are essential as a component needs to be assigned to each menu item for that page to work. If uninstalling core components was possible, some people might end up installing all their components and wonder why their site isn't working

Answer (score 1):

While there might be some benefits in making Joomla lighter, in the current configuration I would say that IS NOT RECOMMENDED to even try something.

Consider using ACL to hide it for the users that don't need it.